# Android: RecyclerView start dragging increase row height

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm beginner of Android and now I have problem of scrolling recycler view. when i bind data to recycler and first run it will show as normal, but when I start drag the list it increase height of each row of recycler. I don't know what the real problem is.

[Image When first loading](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xa96N.jpg)

[Image When start dragging](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RnmFz.jpg)

```
A. My source code in activity_main.xml

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scrollbars="vertical" /></RelativeLayout>

B. My code in MainActivity.xml

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    movieAdapter = new MovieAdapter(movieList);
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    recyclerView.setAdapter(movieAdapter);
    this.loadMovieData();

C. Method loadMovieData()

 private void loadMovieData(){
    for(int i=1;i<=15;i++){
        Movie movie = new Movie("Movie"+i,"Genre"+i,"2015");
        movieList.add(movie);
    }
    movieAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: are u confirm your row layout for recyclerview is correct, please check that one may be its possible something is wrong in row layout

Comment: yes i found it. thank you bro

Comment: anytime, we are here to help

Comment: i met the same problem.what is the problem,help me

Answer (score 0):

Change RecyclerView's height from

`android:layout_height="wrap_content"`

to

`android:layout_height="match_parent"`.
Hope I helped you.

Comment: From "match_parent" to "wrap_content"

Comment: @Socheat Actually, it's from `wrap_content` to `match_parent`.
The `RecyclerView` must have the same height as its parent, and on the code posted, it's `wrap_content`